# Mule Management Console customization

Tags: mule

We need to customize Mule management console. Kindly let us know process/link related to documentation. Example customization - JMX bean display - value part text box is small - for large string values it needs to wrap, create new tab for query purpose based on mbean data or any other information.

Thanks

Comment: Being the Mule Management Console an EE feature, probably you'd get better answers by contacting MuleSoft Support

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely that its supported because its deployed as a war within Tomcat. You might be able to force tomcat (via modifing unpacked war files) to load your own css, but you'll have to do it afresh each time a new version of MMC comes out.

The only customization I'm aware of can be found here:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Customizing+the+Dashboard